# How can I append IPs (a whole class C range) to a file using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

How can I use shell scripting to append a range of IPs to a file?

Comment: Yes you can. `echo "192.168.0.1/24" >> /path/to/file`.

Comment: Oh, or do you need it that way? `echo 192.168.0.{0..255} >> /path/to/file`

Comment: Please, [classes don't exist from eons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). You are referring to a /24.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..255}
do
    echo 192.168.0.$i >>outfile.txt
done
```

The `>>` operator is used to append to a file.

Comment: Thank you so much!! 

ps.: I know I should have found it out by myself, but I know next to nothing about shell scripting, and was (am) dead tired after adding the whole /24 range by hand in a web console (Apache/Tomcat).

I'll try not to ask stupid questions next time!